SurfaceCreated callback not called when I use a NavHost component
I am facing an issue with my Jetpack Compose App.
I use a SurfaceView to display OpenGL or Vulkan content.
In this surfaceView, I have a SurfaceCreated callback which is called on one of my jetpack compose app but not on my second App.
SurfaceView is like this:
public final class VkSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {

    public VkSurfaceView(Context pContext, long pViewCPtr) {
        super(pContext, pViewCPtr);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        SurfaceHolder sh = getHolder();
        Log.i(TAG, "getHolder"+ sh.toString());
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    /**
     * This method is part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface.
     */
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder pHolder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Surface will be created");
    }

I use an AndroidView to use this SurfaceView in my jetpack Compose App:
@Composable
fun MapView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onMapViewAttached: (mapView : VMEMapView) -> Unit = { }
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .clipToBounds(), // Occupy the max size in the Compose UI tree

        factory = { context ->
            VMEMapView(context,null).also {
                onMapViewAttached(it)
            }
        },

        update = {
            
        }
    )
}


In my first working App, I use this type of code:
@Composable
fun ContentView(
    onMapViewCreated: (VMEMapView) -> Unit = {},
    loadMapDataRequested: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    MapView(
        onMapViewAttached = { mapView ->
            onMapViewCreated(mapView)
        }
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
    }
}

In this case, all is working.
But I have now another App which uses the MapView in some jetpack components:
@Composable
fun MapScreen(onMapViewAttached: (mapView : VMEMapView) -> Unit = { }) {
    MapView(
        onMapViewAttached = { mapView ->
            onMapViewAttached(mapView)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
    private fun ScaffoldContent(
        navController: NavHostController,
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        drawerState: DrawerState,
        bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                bottomBar()
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                    text = { },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "") },
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            drawerState.apply {
                                if (isClosed) open() else close()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        )
        { contentPadding ->
            // Screen content
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)) {
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
                    composable("home") { HomeScreen() }
                    composable("map") {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .background(Color.Yellow)
                                .padding(32.dp)
                        ) {
                            MapScreen(
                                onMapViewAttached = { mapView ->
                                    viewModel.loadMapView(this@MainActivity, mapView)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    composable("search") { SearchScreen() }
                    composable("settings") { SettingsScreen() }
                }
            }
        }
    }

In this case, surfaceCreated callback is never called. I tried to check if my MapView have a correct size and it seems ok as I set up a background with color and I can see this green color...
@Composable
fun MapView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onMapViewAttached: (mapView : VMEMapView) -> Unit = { }
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green)
            .clipToBounds(), // Occupy the max size in the Compose UI tree

        factory = { context ->
            VMEMapView(context, attributeSet = null).also {
                onMapViewAttached(it)

            }
        },

        update = { view ->
           
        }
    )
}

Am I doing something bad which prevents the surfaceCreated to be called ?
Thanks !
I tried to set size but I still have the same issue.

getHolder() might attach the callback somewhere else.

Is that possible that the context is different in ScaffoldContent or maybe Scope ? Maybe that's the reason why surfaceCreated is not called...

I searched more and it seems that the ModalNavigationDrawer prevents surfaceCreated to be called. I don't know if it's an issue with the scope or something else...

I was able to resolve the issue putting the NavHost outside of the ModalNavigationDrawer . In this case, SurfaceCreated is called.
